# Base de projeto em AngularJS com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, codeigniter

Olá,

Estou tendo dificuldades em criar uma base de pastas usando angularJS e codeigniter.

Alguns exemplos que procurei na internet deixava todo os arquivos do angular dentro de uma pasta chamada "app" na raiz, outros exemplos deixavam dentro da pasta "assets/js/angular".

Qual regra de pastas seria o correto?

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe regra que defina em qual pasta os arquivos devem ficar. O que você pode fazer e utilizar um conjunto de boas práticas, você mesmo pode criar ou utilizar um existente.

Existem algumas perguntas no S.O em Inglês que possam te ajudar:

[Codeigniter assets folder best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice)

[How to structure Codeigniter Application with Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574329/how-to-structure-codeigniter-application-with-angular-js)